# how to figure out how to authenticate myself using http requests

Tags: authentication, web-scraping, python-requests, session-cookies

I am trying to log in to a site using requests as follows:

```
s = requests.Session()
login_data = {"userName":"username", "password":"pass", "loginPath":"/d2l/login"}
resp = requests.post("https://d2l.pima.edu/d2l/login?login=1", login_data)
```

although I am getting a 200 response, when I say

```
print(resp.content)
b"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset='utf-8' /><script>var hash = window.location.hash;if( hash ) hash = '%23' + hash.substring( 1 );window.location.replace('/d2l/login?sessionExpired=0&target=%2fd2l%2ferror%2f404%2flog%3ftargetUrl%3dhttp%253A%252F%252Fd2l.pima.edu%253A80%252Fd2l%252Flogin%253Flogin%253D1' + hash );</script><title></title></head><body></body></html>"
```

notice it says session expired. 
What I've tried: 
logging back out and in in the actual browser, no success. 
http basic auth, no success.

I'm thinking maybe I need to authenticate myself to this site using cookies?

If so how do I determine which cookies to send it?

I tried figuring this out by saying

```
resp.cookies
Out[4]: <RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

shouldn't this be giving me names of cookies? I'm not sure what to do with such output.
Main Point: HOW DO I FIGURE OUT HOW TO AUTHENTICATE MYSLEF TO THIS WEBSITE?
Help is appreciated.
I would rather not use selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From loading this page https://d2l.pima.edu/d2l/login and viewing its source, you'll notice the POST target path is `/d2l/lp/auth/login/login.d2l`.  Try using that as your POST path.  Your other fields look consistent with the form's expectations.

Note: with python `requests` if you create a session object use it to make your requests:

```
resp = s.post(<blah blah>, login_data)
```

The session will hold any cookies set by the login server, and you can continue to use the `s` object to make requests in the authenticated session.

Comment: what is a post path? I did this:
resp = s.post("https://d2l/lp/auth/login/login.d2l", login_data)
it gave me an error

Comment: try this:
```
resp = s.post("https://d2l.pima.edu/d2l/lp/auth/login/login.d2l", login_data)
```
^^ this URL starts with `https://` (hidden by MD rendering)